# Multi data center for Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-go

Does clickhouse Multi Master or multi data center set up support?
Any other solutions for multi data center replication for clickhouse?

Comment: look at this [Webinar: Introduction to the Mysteries of ClickHouse Replication](https://www.altinity.com/webinarspage/2019/7/31/introduction-to-the-mysteries-of-clickhouse-replication)

Answer (score 7):

CH is multi-master only.

CH is multi / geo DC out the box. There are many users with cross-ocean DCs.

The only requirement is proper latency for Replicated* Engines. 
**All!!!!!** ZK nodes should be in the same DC or in DCs with latency < 50ms. CH loading nodes (which ingest data) should be as close as possible to ZK (better <100ms). Non-loading replicas can be far -- 150-250ms.

Cross-ocean setup needs proper configuration of load-balancing to run queries on local-DC replicas and tuning some params (connect_timeout_with_failover_ms -- 50ms by default).

Answer (score 1):

yes, clickhouse can be setup as multi-DC

please read about Distributed engine

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/table_engines/distributed/

also look to load_balancing settings

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-load_balancing