Multi region Clickhouse deployment configuration
Say I have to design a Clickhouse cluster in a multi region mode with 9 nodes in DC1 and DC2 with 5 shards and 3 replicas for each shard, how do I go about this? I have some idea from the documentation on how to do it within one single region but the documentation is not pretty clear on how it can done with multiple regions? Do we repeat the same configuration file in another DC with a different cluster name ? In that case , how do we configure this ? Does this get handled via Zookeeper configuration across regions ? If so , how does this configuration look like? Any sample will be of great help!!!

You can use the same cluster name and same zookeeper cluster.  It doesn't work any differently than a single DC, although there is some replication delay and zookeeper is slower because of the need to coordinate distributed voting among the zookeeper nodes.
In general however this is a complex topic that can't be answered in a Stack Overflow question.

@GeoffGenz
If the cluster cannot be separated with different name , how can we ensure that the DC2 is just a copy of the DC1? Wont this cause the shards to be split across DCs? The main purpose of multi DC is to generate a copy of DC1 in DC2 and not distribute this data across multiple regions . So , do you suggest using multiple cluster definitions with respective zookeeper clusters mapped to it? In that case , any clue on how Zookeepers communicate to sync this data across will be of great help!!

check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731430/multi-data-center-for-clickhouse/59737859#59737859
